# Can't get access to the Activity item in onItemClick method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onitemclicklistener

I have a Fragment where I get access to the `m_items`-layout:

```
public class MoviesListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_items, container, false);
```

I created a custom adapter (extending the BaseAdapter class) that uses another layout as each list item belonging to the `m_items`-layout:

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), initData());
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

On the layout, which uses the adapter, there is the textView with the identifier `@+id/textID`. I'm trying to set text to it in `onItemClick`-method:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView movie_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textID);
        movie_id.setText("577");
    }
});
```

but get an exception **java.lang.NullPointerException** here: `movie_id.setText("577");`

As I understand it, `view.findViewById(R.id.textID);` returns null.

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the contents of the layout file where textID is specified?

Comment: Does your adapter `getView()` return views with `textID` in them?

Comment: If R.id.textID is on the Activity or Fragment layout, you can make it a member variable of MoviesListFragment and access this variable inside onItemClick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View` argument to `onItemClick()` corresponds to the `View` you returned from your adapter's `getView()`.

To find a child view from it, make sure the view you return from `getView()` in fact contains a view with the given id (`textID`).